# How do you see if directory exists in Firebase Database using Javascript as to not overwrite data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a blog to further my Firebase skills but want to be able to see if a blog with the same slug (title with only letters, and spaces replaced with hyphens) exists in the database. Here is the structure of my Database where all of the slugs will fall under the category "projects".
[image: Database Structure]

This is the code I have but it will always return false regardless of slug:

```
firebase.database().ref().child(projectRef + 'projects/').child(slug).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    alert(exists);
});
```

Any help is very appreciated, and if there is an easier way I am always eager to learn!

Comment: The screenshot you show doesn't have a `projects`, which would explain. I'd also recommend using `snapshot.exists()`, but expect the result to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataSnapshot.hasChild to determine if a certain child exists.

```
firebase.database().ref(projectRef + 'projects/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild(slug)) {
        alert('exists');
    }
 });
```

Note: slug is the blog title you are trying to check

Comment: what do I put in place of blogRef? firebase.database().ref().child(projectRef + 'projects/') or somthing else?

Comment: try referencing the node directly `firebase.database().ref(projectRef + 'projects/')` without the `.child()` and also ensure the `projectRef+/projects/` is targetting the right node. Use this as a guide [firebase.database.DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)